# Errors in Solving Heat Equation

Tags: differential-equations, heat-equation

I am have trouble with what should be a fairly simple NDSolve operation for the unsteady state heat transfer in a rod. The rod starts off at 20oC, and its surface temperature is fixed at 37oC. I am fairly new to Mathematica, so I'm not sure what is going wrong! I keep getting the error `"Infinite expression 1/0. encountered."'

My code is:

```
 a = 0.010
    Cp = 2000
    k = 0.1
    rho = 900
    alpha = k/(rho*Cp)

    Tval[r_, t_] = NDSolve[{

   (* PDE - 1D Radial Heat Equation *)
   (1/r)*(D[(r*D[T[r, t], r]), r]) == (1/alpha)*D[T[r, t], t],

   (* Boundary Conditions *)
   T[a, t] == 37,
   (D[T[r, t], r] /. r -> 0) == 0,

   (* Initial Condition *)
   T[r, 0] == 20},

(* Define Variables *)
  T[r, t], {r, 0, a}, {t, 0, 1800}]

Plot[{Tval[r,0],Tval[r,100],Tval[r,200]},{r,0,a}]
```

If anyone can work out why I am getting division by zero that would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would tend to think your equation has an actual singularity at $r=0$ and that it is wrong. By rod, do you mean disk? Maybe this is useful: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeatConductionEquationDisk.html.

Comment: Replace `0` by some small number, say 10^-4, as the inner boundary in `r`, and `NDSolve` will work.  Define `Tval[r_, t_] =  T[r, t] /. Flatten@NDSolve[...`, and `Plot` will work too.

Comment: However, `T[a, t] == 37` and `T[r, 0] == 20` together have the effect of assigning `T[a, 0]` two different values, which could be a problem.

Comment: @anderstood:  The ODE is correct.  It does have a singular point at $r = 0$, but it is a [regular singular point](https://www.math.ksu.edu/math240/math240.f10/book/chap4/regsing.php), which means that you can find well-behaved series solutions in the neighborhood of $r = 0$.  This is a common problem that has to be dealt with when doing PDEs in curvilinear coordinates;  it arises from the fact that $\vec{\nabla}r$ is not well-defined at that point.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert So there is a singularity, induced by the parametrisation and not the physics, interesting.  Thank you for the informative comment & link.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert All the definitions I find about regular singular points concern ODEs, but here it is a PDE. Would you have a definition in the PDE case?

Comment: @anderstood:  I'm not sure what the definition would be for a PDE, to be honest—or if such a notion would even be useful.  I would instead recommend you look into "separation of variables", which is a technique for finding solutions to PDEs in terms of products of solutions of ODEs;  it's the context where I most frequently see this issue arise.

Comment: Version 12.1 has a tutorial on [Heat Transfer Modeling](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html)

Answer (score 2):

This gives a solution when boundary and initial condition get matched with a very steep rise of the temperature at r=a and r starts from a very small value, not 0:

```
    Tval[r_, t_] = 
                  T[r, t] /. 
            First@NDSolve[{(*PDE-1D Radial Heat Equation*)(1/
                 r)*(D[(r*D[T[r, t], r]), r]) == (1/alpha)*D[T[r, t],t],
    T[a, t] == 37 (1 - (37 - 20)/37 E^(-8 t)), (D[T[r, t], r] /. r -> 10^-8) ==
                0, T[r, 0] == 20}, T, {r, 10^-8, a}, {t, 0, 1800}]
```